# How to use UIDatePicker (countdown timer) to select 0 hour 0 minute?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uipickerview, uidatepicker

As per my product specification, I have to let the user to select 0 hour and 0 minutes, I have  tried with date picker but its not allowing( default 1 minute got selected). What to do now? I googled and got to know its not allowed, Is there any other control I can use? If so will it behave like UIDatePicker (with countdown timer mode)? Thanx..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a UIPicker. You can insert data like 0,5,10,15,etc minutes.

Answer (score 2):

You can set date picker to 00 programmatically in viewDidLoad:

```
NSDateComponents * components = [cal components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
  [components setHour:0];
  [components setMinute:0];
  [comps setSecond:0];
  NSDate * date = [cal dateFromComponents:components];
  [self.datePicker setDate:date animated:TRUE];
```

Comment: Will it allow to select 0 minute 0 hour in GUI?

Comment: no this method does not work! Does not allow 0 to be selected under minutes

Answer (score -3):

Just set the pickers mode...

`[datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer];`

Then have the desired behavior.

Comment: He's already using that mode. This doesn't solve the problem (setting 0 hours and 0 mins).